# No drop shadow in a custom WPF tool-tip on Windows Server 2012

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I created a custom tool-tip with style defined in .xaml files loaded on application startup or when the user changes application theme. Because the tool-tip is used by multiple controls with only slight differences for each of them, I decided to create a separate resource dictionary file with all style definitions that are common to all controls that use the tool-tip. On the other hand, I put all control-specific styles to separate resource dictionary files. Those files use a merged dictionary with a reference to the file with the common styles I mentioned.

The base file contains multiple style definitions, and at least one of them has a style trigger defined. The trigger shows drop shadow when a dependency property HasDropShadow of the tool-tip is set to true. The style is extended in the control-specific files (using the BasedOn attribute).

For some reason, when I run the app on Windows Server 2012, the drop shadow is not visible. On the other hand, when I run the app on Windows 7, the drop shadow is visible as expected. Is something wrong with the way I declared the binding or does Windows affect the tool-tip's HasDropShadow property in any way?

Please note that when I set the Effect property directly, without using triggers, the drop shadow is always visible, even on Windows 2012.

Do you have an idea what could cause this behaviour?

Here is the base StyleBase_User_ToolTip.xaml file (I removed unrelated content from it):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Client="clr-namespace:Client;assembly=Client">

    <Style x:Key="ToolTipBorderBase" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,10,10,10" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />

        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\User_ToolTip\background_bar.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <!--drop shadow visibility-->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Client:User_ToolTip}, Path=HasDropShadow}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.4"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ToolTipContent" TargetType="Client:User_ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Client:User_ToolTip}">

                    <Border Style="{DynamicResource ToolTipBorder}">
                        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ToolTipContentContainer}">
                            ...
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here is one of the control-specific files:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Client="clr-namespace:Client;assembly=Client">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <ResourceDictionary Source="StyleBase_User_ToolTip.xaml" />

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="ToolTipBorder" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToolTipBorderBase}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,8,8" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you are by setting the style "ToolTipBorder" in any control?

Comment: If you copy the DataTrigger to the `ToolTipBorder` Style, does it work? It sounds weird to me that Style inheritance works fine in some OS and not in others, sounds more like a problem with default styles and system themes.

Comment: @NicolasDias I use the style in a Border within the tool-tip's Template. I've just edited the question and added the missing part for you.

Comment: @almulo Actually I'm quite confused about the fact that the behaviour is OS-dependent. However, not long ago I had a similar situation in another style. I had a trigger with a storyboard defined in a style in one file, and a derived style in another file. When the control that used the style was attached to the base style, the trigger worked perfectly fine. When I attached it to the derived style, it never worked (and I don't think it was OS-dependent that time). Let me mention that I use dynamic resource bindings, eg. Style="{DynamicResource MyStyleKey}".

Comment: @almulo I've already checked what happens when I assign the drop shadow directly to the Effect property of the Border without using any triggers, and in that case the shadow is always visible as expected. Please give me a while and I'll check what you asked for as well.

Comment: @almulo I moved the trigger to the derived style and the drop shadow remained not visible on Windows Server 2012. Removing the derived style didn't change anything either. This means I was wrong claiming style inheritance had anything to do with this issue, and decided to edit the question. Sorry.

Comment: @almulo Mmmh, I see... Looking at your code, I don't think it's a system themes problem, like I said before, either. It may be a problem of ResourceDictionaries not "seeing" each other or something like that. Have you tried moving the derived Style to the base ResourceDictionary, with the other two, and changing your `DynamicResource` for a `StaticResource`? If not a solution, it would at least give us an idea of what's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. In my example I bound the drop shadow's trigger to the inbuilt HasDropShadow property of my tool-tip. I assigned it a value of True at runtime, but Windows Server 2012 did not show the drop shadow, as opposed to Windows 7.

However, when I declared a separate dependency property to indicate whether the drop shadow should be visible, and bound the above mentioned trigger to it instead, Windows Server 2012 displayed the drop shadow properly.

So, am I right that some dependency properties may have values fully controlled by the OS?

BTW, I forgot to mention that my Client:User_ToolTip is a descendant of System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip.